# Mobile Usability Error - clickable elements too close together

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, mobile, error

I don't quite understand how the mobile usability works but it is detecting the problem on the `wp-includes` path when using Wordpress. What can do to stop it?
[image]

Comment: It is not the path, it is the HTML elements are too close. This means that it is at least difficult if not impossible to click on a link, button, or other element using a mobile device because they are too close. This is likely a poorly designed template/theme for mobile or at least one that needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Google recommends a minimum of 48px (in CSS) of height/width to ensure proper usability on tappable targets. You need to take care of that, and add inline style if possible to override the default theme behaviour and overcome this issue.

Read more here: [Size Tap Targets Appropriately](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/SizeTapTargetsAppropriately)